# Replace anything regex php

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

i have this regex in php

```
$array_item_aux = str_replace('/.*PUBMED=/',"",$array_item);
```

it shoul be replacing this text 
(-|ENSR00001252129|RegulatoryFeature|regulatory_region_variant|-|-|-|-|-|PUBMED=21499247

with this

```
21499247
```

what i'm doing wrong

Comment: For what it's worth, the lazy matching isn't necessary (`.*?` instead of your `.*`) - not entirely sure why people are suggesting this... though it certainly doesn't hurt. Ultimately the change of function as mentioned below is the main issue here.

Comment: The lazy match makes sense for instances where several PUBMED= appears several times in the text upon which it is applied, as .* does match that. But it depends on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace` doesn't use regex, use `preg_replace`:

```
$array_item_aux = preg_replace('/.*?PUBMED=/', "", $array_item);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if the string you show is the whole string, you can use explode:

```
$array_item_aux = explode('PUBMED=', $array_item)[1];
```

If your PHP version is too old (<5.4) for this syntax, you can use instead:

```
$tmp = explode('PUBMED=', $array_item);
$array_item_aux = $tmp[1];
```

or as @Sam suggests it:

```
list(, $array_item_aux) = explode('PUBMED=', $array_item);
```

Comment: This answer should probably include a note/warning regarding PHP version availability.. (but is of course a good alternative method!)

Comment: Just a note for people interested in this answer: "too old" < 5.4.0

Comment: Another alternative for old PHP is `list(, $array_item_aux) = explode('PUBMED=', $array_item);`

Comment: @Sam: nice syntax, I will add it

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `.*` [lazy instead of a greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) by adding a `?`; but your main issue is the fact that `str_replace()` does not allow for searching with regex, instead use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$array_item_aux = preg_replace('/.*?PUBMED=/', '', $array_item);
```